# How to set max-age caching directive in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

If this problem can be solved by google it please provide a link, I tried by could not find any tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is controlled by the Duration option e.g.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600)]
```

See here for the full list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx